# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, each

```
$('img').each(function() {
    if (this.src.indexOf('larger') !== -1) {
        var normalized = this.src.replace('larger', 'normalized');
        console.log('found', normalized);
        window.open(normalized);
    };
});
```

I don't have any experience. I found this snippet and tried to run it but I kept getting  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null. Now it's more about why I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: are you trying to loop img element ?..seems like there is no img element in your code

Comment: @meenakshi Thank you for the reply! I'm truly a noob, I guess even the noobs on this site will understand the vocab you used because I have no idea what id or class means! I only found this script because I tried to download an original image from artsy. instead of this I just searched "zoom" and found the link I needed. Sorry if this was a bit annoying but thank you so much for responding. I'm very interested in coding now lots to learn.

Comment: @meenakshi random question if you're not annoyed at how clueless i am: Once I find the link through searching "zoom" with googlechrome CommandF, I could no longer touch the page or highlight to copy any text anymore. Is this just my computer bugging out?

Comment: @meenakshi doing a .each() on a id selector??? My heart stopped for a second...